# How to make calling of xeCJK work in a group

Tags: packages, grouping, xecjk

From the following example, you can see that calling a package in a group does work (`xcolor` in this example), except the package `xeCJK`.

Does that mean this is a bug of `xeCJK`, or is there  other way to make it work in a group?

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

%...
% Here are some macro definations, package calling etc.
%...

{% all codes from here below are used for test
  \usepackage{xcolor}
  \usepackage{xeCJK}% this line has to be commented  to make the codes work. 
\begin{document}
\colorbox{red}{some text}
\end{document}
}
```

Comment: Everything after `\end{document}` is ignored, so not a "real" grouping.

Comment: What is the purpose of placing the whole document inside a group?

Comment: @Jasper Habicht All codes for test will be put into this group. With the help of a conditional variable,  after test, only definations in preamble are to be used for being called by other files.

Comment: @Cicada Since this is not a real group, why calling of `xeCJK` leads to error and not by `xcolor`?

Comment: you should never load a package in a group. That will break lots of things.

Comment: Thank you @ Ulrike Fischer By now, most packages I have ever used confirm to work well in this way, except `xeCJK`. So is this a problem of xeCJK, or some other reasons? And are there such macros like `\global` to work with `\usepackage`?

Comment: Look in the log: ctex goes into infinite loop. It has to check systems and call packages conditionally etc, so that would be part of the picture.

Comment: I told you not to do it. If you insist to reject my advice you are on your own.

Comment: Only because using `\usepackage` in a grop works for some packages, this does not mean that you should do it. As this is not the intended way to load a package, it is likeliy that things break. And in fact they do with the `xeCJK` package. But, as this is not the way any package should be loaded, it is hardly a problem of this package. This also should answer your question regarding the use of `\global` in combination with `\usepackage`: No, there is no such a way (at least not to my knowledge), because packages are in general intended to be loaded globally anyways (i.e. not inside a group).

Comment: @Jasper Habicht, Ulrike Fischer, Cicada Thnank you so much for your advice and excellent explanation of this post!! I don't mean insisting on my idea of loading packages in a group. I just want to know more about package loading which I have not focusd more. As my idea is absolutely wrong, I'll try in other way.

Comment: See `iftex` and `ifplatform` packages for detecting engines and OS.

Comment: Expl3 has functions like `\sys_if_engine_xetex:...` (e.g., see in package `ctex-spa-macro.tex`). Do `texdoc interface3` for expl3 documentation.

Comment: do not use `\usepackage` in a group, it can almost never work and if it ever seems to do anything useful that is accidental unsupported behaviour.

Comment: Thank you @ David Carlisle. The point of this post, or what confuses me is: Though packages calling and document body are in the same group (top level), using of a certain package(here is xeCJK) still causes error.